# Pundit with namespaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

The `policy_scope` works perfectly finding the correct policy named `Admin::RemittancePolicy` but  `authorize` method not.

```
module Admin
  class RemittancesController < AdminController # :nodoc:
    ...

    def index
      @remittances = policy_scope(Remittance).all

      render json: @remittances
    end

    def show
      authorize @remittance

      render json: @remittance
    end

    ...
  end
end
```

Take a look at output error:

```
"#<Pundit::NotDefinedError: unable to find scope `RemittancePolicy::Scope` for `Remittance(...)`>"
```

Perhaps a error with pundit, I really not know how fix it. Thanks.

---

More information below:

```
# policies/admin/admin_policy.rb
module Admin
  class AdminPolicy < ApplicationPolicy # :nodoc:
    def initialize(user, record)
      @user = user
      @record = record.is_a?(Array) ? record.last : record
    end

    def scope
      Pundit.policy_scope! user, record.class
    end

    class Scope # :nodoc:
      attr_reader :user, :scope

      def initialize(user, scope)
        @user = user
        @scope = scope.is_a?(Array) ? scope.last : scope
      end

      def resolve
        scope
      end
    end
  end
end

# controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb
module Admin
  class AdminController < ActionController::API # :nodoc:
    include Knock::Authenticable
    include Pundit

    before_action :authenticate_user

    after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index
    after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index

    # def policy_scope!(user, scope)
    #   model = scope.is_a?(Array) ? scope.last : scope
    #   PolicyFinder.new(scope).scope!.new(user, model).resolve
    # end

    def policy_scope(scope)
      super [:admin, scope]
    end

    def authorize(record, query = nil)
      super [:admin, record], query
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does the `show?` method look like for your `Admin::RemittancePolicy`  ? You say `policy_scope` works perfectly and `authorize` works fine, but I have a feeling the error you pasted is not directly from any of the code you've provided. How about showing the full error too?

Comment: `show` does nothing now. Thanks to try help me. The complete stack here https://gist.github.com/brunowego/c9ce9a709fcec94e0d313f32dbc645ae

Comment: Only `policy_scope` are going correctly to `Admin::RemittancePolicy`. The `authorize` are going to `RemittancePolicy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stacktrace says the error comes from

```
app/policies/admin/admin_policy.rb:9:in 'scope'
```

That's this:

```
def scope
  Pundit.policy_scope! user, record.class
end
```

`record.class` evaluates to `Remittance`, so if I understand what you're trying to do, you need to change `scope` to

```
def scope
  Pundit.policy_scope! user, [:admin, record.class]
end
```

Comment: Exactly I am looking for, so simple. Thanks!